# In webapi, How to get absolute url path of an image located in local IIS?

Tags: image, asp.net-web-api

I am a novice to webapi. i have used two projects in an webapi solution. one project forms url of image which is located in iis. second project sends image to first project to form http url link. In second project, I need to get absolute path. for that I have used,  `string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"..\Images\imageNotFound.jpg");` but object reference not found exception occurred. I also tried `string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");` object reference not found exception occurred. Kindly help to identify the absolute path

> `for eg. http://localhost/images/image1.jpg.`